# Avoid javascript's variables reset when user uses back and foward

Tags: javascript

Well,

I Have a countdown timer, and I'm facing the following problem:

My countdown starts at 90 seconds. If the user waits until it reaches 2 seconds, for example, then he goes back using browser's button and after goes forward (backing to the same page), the countdown restarts at 90 seconds, not at 2 as I need, because when the timer reaches 0 I "click" at a button which post the form.

I know I need to handle the back and forward button and set my variable with the new value but I don't have any idea how can I do it. Any help will be great.

My code is below:

```
var count = 90;
var screenCount = count;
var newCount = 0;
function countFunction() {

    if (screenCount != 0) {
    var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
    var seconds = count - minutes * 60;        
    if (count > 60){
        if (seconds < 10)
            seconds = "0" + seconds;
        screen = minutes + "m:" + seconds + "s";
        $('.timer').css('width',"120px")
    }
    else{            
        if (count < 10)
            screen = "0" + count;
        else
            screen = count + "s";            
        $('.timer').css('width',"60px")
    }
    document.getElementById('tempo').innerHTML = screen;
    if (count == 0) {
         set('temporizador', screenCount);
          $(":submit").removeAttr("disabled");
        $('#responder').click(); 

    }
    if (count != 0) {
         set('temporizador',screenCount - count );
        count = count - 1;
        setTimeout("countFunction()", 1000);
    }
    } 
    else {
        document.getElementById('tempo').innerHTML = '∞';

        set('temporizador', newCount);

         newCount++;
        setTimeout("countFunction()", 1000);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user presses back a whole new page is loaded, with an entirely new Javascript context. If you want to pass information from the context of one page to the context of another, there are several ways to do it.

In your particular situation, using LocalStorage is the easiest:

```
// count down 90 seconds, including page navigation on this site
var count = +localStorage.getItem('timerCount') || 90;

function countDown() {
  count--;
  localStorage.setItem('timerCount', count);
  if (count<0) window.clearInterval(myInterval);
}

var myInterval = window.setInterval(countDown, 1000);
```

**Suggestion by @DmitryVolokh**

In this example i stored the remaining time in localStorage. If you want to track the elapsed time from a particular moment, you would be better served to store the starting time instead and compute the difference.

Comment: Guess, storing just timerCount is not enough. Imaging the situation, that timerCount=40 and user navigates on new page that loads really slowly and script starts after 5 seconds. This 5 seconds will be lost.  So, in case author needs real countdown - he store a pair: timerCount and current time.

Comment: @DmitryVolokh Indeed, i will add your suggestion to the answer.

Comment: Very good answer, I just needed remove count-- at countdown function to adapt to my code because it was setting 2 seconds instead 1. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You use local storage for this as suggested above but there is the slight issue that some older browsers don't support localStorage: http://caniuse.com/#search=local%20storage

Since you are only storing a single number you could also use a cookie:

```
var match, count;
if (match = /timerCount=(\d+);/.exec(document.cookie)) {
  count = match[1];
} else {
  count = 90
}

function countDown() {
  count--;
  document.cookie = 'timerCount=' + count + ';';
  if (count<0) window.clearInterval(myInterval);
}

var myInterval = window.setInterval(countDown, 1000);
```

Comment: Your answer is right too but my users are using the latest versions of browser since my targets are IOS and Android. Thank you very much.

Comment: Cool, yeah localStorage is really nice when you can use it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload) javascript event to see when the users leave the page, and then act as you want : changing the window.location to redirect the user (and give additional parameters like your timer), or prevent him from leaving the page. 
You can also create a [cookie](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) or use [localstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to store the timer and get it back next time user comes to your page.